# Converting an array to a set of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have this array:

```
var myArray =  [{'name': 'name1', 'desc': 'desc1'}, {'name':'name2', 'desc':    
               'desc2'},.....];
```

and i wanted to turn it into objects like this:

```
var myobject = {
    obj1: {
        name: 'name1',
        desc: 'desc1',
    },
    obj2 = {
        name: 'name2',
        desc: 'desc2'
    },
    .....
}
```

I want to iterate through myArray and return an object like myobject .

Thanks

Comment: why not just use the indexer?

Comment: There is nothing about JSON here. These are regular JavaScript objects/arrays.

Comment: You showed the solution, so there's a way ;) Explain better you problem, what's the motivation behind it?

Comment: please explain what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: Actualy it has been done already, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray['0'])); console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray['1'])); alert('Arrays are Objects too!');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myArray =  [{'name': 'name1', 'desc': 'desc1'}, {'name':'name2', 'desc':    
           'desc2'}];

var myObject = {};

for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
  myObject["obj"+i] = myArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
  window['json' + (i + 1)] = myArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Note that `str + num + num` will do concatenation, so it will become `json01` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop or just use the array's indexes like so:

```
var myArray =  [{'name': 'name1', 'desc': 'desc1'}, {'name':'name2', 'desc': 'desc2'}];

var json1 = myArray[0];
var json2 = myArray[1];


console.log( json1.name );
```